# Image file path cannot upload to MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP, I try to upload the image file path in MySQL Database, but the path cannot upload and it always shows as NULL my code are provide below.

```
                if(isset($_FILES['img']) && $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] != ''){
                    $fname = 'uploads/avatar-'.($id).'.png';
                    $dir_path =base_app. $fname;
                    $upload = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
                    $type = mime_content_type($upload);
                    $allowed = array('image/png','image/jpeg');
                    if(!in_array($type,$allowed)){
                        $resp['msg']=" But Image failed to upload due to invalid file type.";
                    }else{
                        $new_height = 200; 
                        $new_width = 200; 
                
                        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($upload);
                        $t_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                        imagealphablending( $t_image, false );
                        imagesavealpha( $t_image, true );
                        $gdImg = ($type == 'image/png')? imagecreatefrompng($upload) : imagecreatefromjpeg($upload);
                        imagecopyresampled($t_image, $gdImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
                        if($gdImg){
                                if(is_file($dir_path))
                                unlink($dir_path);
                                $uploaded_img = imagepng($t_image,$dir_path);
                                imagedestroy($gdImg);
                                imagedestroy($t_image);
                                if(isset($uploaded_img) && $uploaded_img == true){
                                    $qry = $this->conn->query("UPDATE users set avatar = concat('{$fname}','?v=',unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) where id = '$id' ");
                                }
                        }else{
                        $resp['msg']=" But Image failed to upload due to unkown reason.";
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
```

I want to upload the image file path and display the image

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the provided code, it looks like you're attempting to upload an image and save its path in the MySQL database. If the path is showing as NULL in the database, there could be a few reasons for this. Refer to this resource for the [php framework list](https://www.interviewbit.com/blog/php-frameworks/). Here are some suggestions to troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Directory Permission**: Ensure that the `uploads` directory has the necessary write permissions. The web server needs permission to create and write files in this directory.

   Example (Linux):

   ```bash
   chmod -R 755 uploads
   ```
2. **File Path Construction**: Double-check the construction of the `$dir_path` variable. Ensure that `base_app` contains the correct base path for your application. You can use `echo $dir_path;` to debug and see if the path is constructed correctly.
3. **Database Connection**: Verify that the database connection (`$this->conn`) is established successfully before executing the SQL query. If the connection fails, the query won't be executed, and the database field will remain NULL.

   Example:

   ```php
   if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
   }
   ```
4. **Error Handling**: Implement proper error handling to catch any SQL errors that might occur during the query execution. This can help identify if there are issues with the SQL statement.

   Example:

   ```php
   $qry = $this->conn->query("UPDATE users set avatar = concat('{$fname}','?v=',unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) where id = '$id' ");
   if (!$qry) {
       echo "Error: " . $this->conn->error;
   }
   ```
5. **Database Field Type**: Ensure that the `avatar` field in the database table has an appropriate data type (VARCHAR or TEXT) to store the file path.
6. **Check for SQL Injection**: Although the provided code doesn't show user input directly in the SQL query, always be cautious about SQL injection. If the `$id` variable comes from user input, consider using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

   Example:

   ```php
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users set avatar = concat(?,'?v=',unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) where id = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("si", $fname, $id);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
   ```

By checking these points, you can identify potential issues and resolve why the image path might be showing as NULL in your MySQL database.